# Selecting button in Winform ToolStrip 

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

[image]

**Reference Image**

I want to select a button("Exit") on the ToolStrip after pressing a button ("ButtonFocus To Exit") outside the toolstrip.

I used **ExitToolStripButton.Select()** on ButtonFocusToExit.Click but which seems like its selecting the button ("Exit") but when i pressed enter it never execute the code in **"ExitToolStripButton_Click"** .

So the button is still not active. Can anyone have fix to it?

Comment: Did u soldve it ? Are you still facing problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution ...

First focus on the ToolStrip and then Select the Control on the Toolstrip

*ToolStrip1.Focus()*

*ExitToolStripButton.Select()*

Answer (score 0):

Check if event is missing the event handler

> Select the ExitToolStripButton > go to
>   properties > events tab> Click Event >
>   select the ExitToolStripButton_Click

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute the ExitToolStripButton codebehind? You can call `ExitToolStripButton.PerformClick()`;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it has focus.  Are you sure the function you are using actually give the object focus?  It could just give it the appearance of selection.

According to MSDN:

```
Select  |  Selects the item. (inherited from ToolStripItem)
```

It doesn't say anything about focusing it.